# R gsub replaces special character with nonsense(?) rather than space

Tags: r, gsub

I'm working with Netlogo in BehaviorSpace, and one of the cells in my output table is a string representing 10 different numbers.

Here's a representative mockup of the data:

```
trialmatrix <- matrix(c("[4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4]","[4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4]", "[4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4]"), nrow=3)
trialdf <- data.frame(trialmatrix, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The string is enclosed in []. I'm using R to remove the []s and convert the string into a vector of individual numbers.

But gsub puts in new characters and doesn't remove the []:

```
> gsub("\\[ | \\]", " ", trialdf)
#[1] "c(\" 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4]\", \" 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4]\", \" 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4]\")"
```

Replacing all special characters removes the decimal points and still adds a c:

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", trialdf)
#[1] "c45 68 79 81 90 12 34 45 68 79 81 90 12 34 45 68 79 81 90 12 34"
```

Then I run

```
gsub("c","", trialdf2)
```

to get rid of the c.
Now I have

```
#[1] "45 68 79 81 90 12 34 45 68 79 81 90 12 34 45 68 79 81 90 12 34"
```

and then

```
trial3 <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(trial2, " ")))
```

which gives

```
#[1] 45 68 79 81 90 12 34 45 68 79 81 90 12 34 45 68 79 81 90 12 34
```

which I need to now scale by .1 in order to get the decimals back.

```
trial4 <- trial3 * .1
#[1] 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1 9.0 1.2 3.4
```

NOW it goes back into a dataframe.

```
trialdf2 <- data.frame(matrix(trial4, ncol=7, byrow=TRUE))
#   X1  X2  X3  X4 X5  X6  X7
#1 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1  9 1.2 3.4
#2 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1  9 1.2 3.4
#3 4.5 6.8 7.9 8.1  9 1.2 3.4
```

And then I need to rename all the columns ( the real dataset has up to 200 elements in the character string ) . . .

There MUST be an easier way. And why does the first gsub generate nonsense?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Give `gsub` a vector to parse, say `trialdf[[1]]`, not a data.frame. Pretty sure that's in the docs.

Comment: The linked duplicate might be a deeper dive into the issue than you really need, but as Frank mentioned the solution amounts to the same thing, be careful passing lists (and by extension, data frames) to things that will coerce them via `as.character`.

Comment: ...also you might try an idiom like `trialdf[] <- lapply(trialdf,function(x) { gsub("\\[|\\]", " ", x) })`. (Note the slight change to the regex.)

Comment: Hi, thanks, not sure how the link relates. I'm trying to get rid of the square brackets, and have pretty much worked out how to get the right variable class.

Comment: The link explains why you get the leading `c`, which is what the text of your question explicitly asked for an explanation of. My comment gave you a pointer towards a slightly smoother way to do some of these steps, including removing the brackets. Your approach on the final few steps seems fine.

Comment: what about `as.data.frame(t(sapply(1:3,function(x){as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", trialdf[x,]),' ')[[1]])})))` ?

Comment: And the lapply construct works, thanks!

Comment: Beautiful, Etienne, saved eight lines of code and works a charm.